# Is there a lightweight cross-browser range input solution without any need of libraries like jQuery

Tags: html, input, range

I am searching for a very lightweight solution for a cross-browser range input. I want to avoid to use any JavaScript library like jQuery, which is much more than I need.

I need to be able to support legacy browsers like Internet Explorer 8.

Answer (score 1):

There is the range input, which is HTML5 and supported by most modern browsers:

```
<input type="range"/>
```

Here is the full documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input

However, if you want to be fully compatible you might have to stick with a library solution.

Comment: thank you .. sorry, I didn't write what I mean with cross browser. I also want to support internet explorer down to IE8.

Comment: @user1030151 Don't forget that browsers that do not support the range input type will simply fall back to input type="text" - so this is a good example of "Progressive Enhancement" where users whose browsers do support it get extra functionality without *breaking* the site for legacy browsers. None-the-less you can polyfill support in legacy browsers, see my answer for details on that.

Answer (score 0):

Don't punish the majority of users who are using a modern HTML 5 standards compliant browser by *unconditionally* loading a JavaScript library to replicate native functionality - use the HTML 5 range input and then use a [feature test](http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html) and [polyfill](http://remysharp.com/2010/10/08/what-is-a-polyfill/) to provide support for those browsers that do not natively support the range input type.

If you are wanting to keep things lightweight then I would strongly suggest using the excellent [YepNope conditional loading library](http://yepnopejs.com/) and the test as per the Dive Into HTML5 page, something like-

```
function detectsRange() {
   var testElement = document.createElement('input');
   testElement.setAttribute('type', 'range');
   return (testElement.type === 'range');
}
```

If you don't want to have to worry about detecting the feature yourself, you could use the well regarded [Modernizr library](http://modernizr.com/) to detect support for many HTML5 and CSS3 features.

Both Modernizr and YepNope will allow you to *conditionally* load a script like [jQuery tools Range Input](http://jquerytools.org/demos/rangeinput/index.html) (and any pre-requisites like jQuery that you might not be using already) meaning that only those users with unsupported browsers need download anything.

Comment: Incidentally, the YepNope library does not require jQuery to operate since you specifically listed that as a library you do **not** want to have to rely on. Most polyfills or JavaScript replacements will probably require it though, strengthening the case for conditional loading.